# Having trouble with my full viewport video background using fullpage.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

I have a peculiar problem on my website. I tried replicating the problem in jsfiddle but I couldn't. Therefore I am hoping that some of you guys might have an idea as to why this bug happens on my website.

What I am trying to do is basically this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9rs760bp/10/) But what I end up with is this [http://nova-media.dk](http://nova-media.dk/) and I really cannot understand why the problem keeps occuring. I use the same libraries, the same structure in the html and the same styling as far as I can see - therefore I really have trouble understanding why the background video keeps behaving like this.

The HTML:

```
    <div id="fullpage" class="grid-wrap">
        <div class="section red-box">
            <div class="red">
                <h1>TEXT</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="section green-box">
            <div class="green">
                <h1>MORE TEXT</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
            <div class="section red-box">
            <div class="red">
                <h1>TEXT</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The CSS:

```
.red-box {
background-color: red;
opacity: 0.5;
}
.green-box {
    background-color: green;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

#video-bg {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -100;

    -webkit-filter: blur(8px);
    -moz-filter: blur(8px);
    -o-filter: blur(8px);
    -ms-filter: blur(8px);
    filter: blur(8px);
}
#bgVideo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

}
/* 1. No object-fit support: */
@media (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
    #bgVideo { height: 300%; top: -100%; }
}
@media (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
    #bgVideo { width: 300%; left: -100%; }
}
/* 2. If supporting object-fit, overriding (1): */
@supports (object-fit: cover) {
    #bgVideo {
        top: 0; left: 0;
        width: 100%; height: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
    }
}
```

And the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#fullpage').fullpage({
        scrollingSpeed: 700,
        scrollBar: true,
        anchors:['red', 'green', 'blue']
    });
});
```

Comment: Aaaand I may allready have found the solution. Seems like my mobile menu setup is the cause of all my troubles.